# Should there be a dllmain tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There are a lot of existing questions about DllMain, the function in a Windows DLL that gets called when the DLL is loaded or unloaded and when a thread is starts or exits.  But a tag has never been created.  I think such a tag would be useful, but the guidelines for creating new tags say that they should usually only be created for new topics - it doesn't mention the situation where a tag should probably have been created but wasn't.

What's the right way forwards here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're >1500, so you can make tags.

Just retag some posts with it, and see if it is used. If it isn't, it will automagically be removed from the system.

Since it should have been created, create it!